# How to plot two groups of boxplots on the same figure?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

Say I have an example dataframe below:

```
Division   Home Corners  Away Corners  

Bundesliga   5                 3
Bundesliga   5                 5
EPL          7                 4
EPL          3                 2
League 1     10                6
Serie A      3                 3
Serie A      8                 2
League 1     3                 1
```

I want to create a boxplot of total corners per game grouped by divison, but I want the home corners and away Corners to be separated but on the same figure. Similar to what the "hue" keyword accomplishes, but how do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [`seaborn.boxplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html)

- Reshape the data to a long form with [`pandas.DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = {'Division': ['Bundesliga', 'Bundesliga', 'EPL', 'EPL', 'League 1', 'Serie A', 'Serie A', 'League 1'],
        'Home Corners': [5, 5, 7, 3, 10, 3, 8, 3],
        'Away Corners  ': [3, 5, 4, 2, 6, 3, 2, 1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# convert the data to a long format
df.set_index('Division', inplace=True)
dfl = df.stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1': 'corners', 0: 'val'})

# plot
sns.boxplot('corners', 'val', data=dfl, hue='Division')
plt.legend(title='Division', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can `melt` the original data and use `sns.boxplot`:

```
sns.boxplot(data=df.melt('Division', var_name='Home/Away', value_name='Corners'),
            x='Division', y='Corners',hue='Home/Away')
```

Output:

[image]